# How to get the return value of future

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

Implementation is like this below.

```
Future<Duration?> getCurrentPosition() async {
  final milliseconds = await _platform.getCurrentPosition(playerId);
  if (milliseconds == null) {
    return null;
  }
  return Duration(milliseconds: milliseconds);
}
```

I want to get the `Duration(milliseconds: milliseconds);`

So I wrote this code.

```
Duration t = await widget.audioPlayerHandler.audioPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
```

My code is above.

But this shows error below, somehow it returns `int`??

How can I get the `Duration` that function returns?

```
lib/main.dart:468:18: Error: A value of type 'int' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Duration'.
 - 'Duration' is from 'dart:core'.
    Duration t = await widget.audioPlayerHandler.audioPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things here
This method returns nullable data and milliseconds can only take int.

```dart
Future<Duration?> getCurrentPosition() async {
  final milliseconds = await _platform.getCurrentPosition(playerId);
  if (milliseconds == null) {
    return null;
  }
  return Duration(milliseconds:int.tryParse(milliseconds)??0);
}
```

and get nullable duration like `Duration? t` or provide default value.

```dart
Duration  t = await widget.audioPlayerHandler.audioPlayer.getCurrentPosition()??Duration.zero;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I see the problem is null safety.

Comment: Glad to help you can check more about [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)